# GoogleMaps API latitude and longitude returned differently

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I use the googleMaps API to get location data from a given address:

```
function geocodeAddress(address, callback) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ address: address }, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                callback(results[0].geometry.location);
            } else {
                console.log("No results found");
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
    });
}

function getLatLng(address, callback) {
    latLng = [];
    geocodeAddress(address, function(position) {
        latLng.push(position.lat());
        latLng.push(position.lng());
        callback(latLng);
    });
}

// Search for address provided by user via Google Maps API
setMapToSearchAddress: function() {
    var vm = this;

    // Set the location in map to the address given
    setMapLocationToAddress(this.searchAddress);
    getLatLng(this.searchAddress, function(latlng) {
        console.log(latlng);
        vm.latitude = latlng[0];
        vm.longitude = latlng[1];
    })
}
```

But when I send a POST request to my server and print the output of the request being sent, I see, that the longitude is sent as a number, whereas the latitude is sent as a string. But I never converted the data?

```
function postDataToServer(endpoint, data, callback) {
    $.post("v1/".concat(endpoint), function(data, response) {
        callback(response);
    })
}

   createIncident: function() {
        var incidentData = {
            "incidentReference": "",
            "latitude": this.latitude,
            "longitude": this.longitude,
            "streetName": this.address,
            "featureTypeId": 1,
            "archived": 0
        }

        console.log(incidentData);

        // POST data to server
        postDataToServer("incidents", incidentData, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
    },
```

> Object {incidentReference: "", latitude: "48.15312", longitude:
>   11.583509999999933, streetName: "Leopoldstraße 8", featureTypeId: 1…}archived: 0featureTypeId: 1incidentReference: ""latitude:
>   "48.15312"longitude: 11.583509999999933streetName: "Leopoldstraße 8"

Why are these variables treated differently?

Comment: form-data will always be sent as string, so the type of the data(before sending) is not important(except you send a JSON-string) . Maybe it's simply an issue with the console(which browser are you using)

Comment: I found out that the $.post seems to be the problem. I get an error, that the latitude property is not being received by the server. hm..

Comment: Are you sure your server is receiving any data? It looks like your `$.post` syntax might be incorrect because you're trying to send the data via the success callback function. Maybe try `$.post("v1/".concat(endpoint), data, function(response) { ...`?